# ¿Como enviar texto de un input a un label con js en tiempo real?

Tags: javascript, html, input, text

Quiero cambiar el texto de un label por el texto que ingreso a un input, pero no funciona lo que tengo, he probado con keypress, keyup y keydown:
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="txtDesc">
<label id="lblDesc"></label>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    var lblDesc = document.getElementById("lblDesc"
    var desc = document, descTest = desc.getElementById("txtDesc");
    prueba.addEventListener("keyup",function(j){
            lblDesc = String.fromCharCode(desc);
    });
});
```

Y bueno no paso nada, lo logre hacer con una función OnClick, pero quiero que sea a tiempo real, por favor necesito ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

debes usar el evento oninput

el codigo seria mas o menos asi:

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
</script>
```

aqui te dejo un enlace con el ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_oninput

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funciono

Answer (score 0):

Lograr eso es muy facil con angular, pero tratandose de Vanilla JS yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```html
<html>
<head>
   <title>Ejemplo getElementById</title>
</head>
<script>
  function changeValue(newColor) {
   var valor = document.getElementById('campo').value;
   document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = valor;
}
</script>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="campo" onkeyup="changeValue(this.value)">
   <p id="para">Cualquier texto acá</p>
</body>
</html
```